# Is it better to create separate projects for each OS or mix them all into one project?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, project-management

Is it better to create separate projects for each OS or to mix OS specific code into one project?

For example, is it better to keep using these in C++ or totally just bypass these definitions by doing it differently for each OS but keeping the same actual end result and process:

```
#ifdef __WIN32
    // Do Windows stuff
#endif
```

I feel like it'd be a lot easier to manage and re-factor code that's specific for each OS but then again it'd be more compiling, debugging and testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have to code for multiple OS, I create the code which is independent of the OS in seperate modules and the OS specific is handled in seperate classes.

Depending on your needs you can also look at cross platform libraries like `Qt` to handle platform specific code.

Using `#ifdef` is not the best way, to handle this, and should be avoided if possible. Creating proper classes to abstract your needs are the way to go.

Since you are talking about projects, this is a different level. You can use tools like `CMake` to create build environments for the various platforms. The you can link the platform specific classes to your code, without changes to your main code.

Comment: So, cross platform projects should be properly done via OOP principles like abstraction? I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean like creating classes that have the exact same APIs but having them in different folders e.g. linux/ windows/ mac/ etc. and using ifdef to determine what classes get included?

Comment: You don't even need ifdefs for that, because you have different project files anway. So you use linux_class.cpp for the linux version and windows_class.cpp for the windows version in your respective project. The API of the class will always be the same, only the cpp file is different.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use some framework library like [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/); they are giving you some single interface wrapping operating system specific calls.

I would suggest, if you want to do yourself various OS mappings, to define some common abstraction and have very few files which are OS specific. Having a lot of `#ifdef LINUX` or `#ifdef _WIN32` everywhere is a maintenance nightmare.